# Angular Select shows MatIcon as a part of value

Tags: angular, angular-material

Here is my code:

```
<mat-select
  >
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
      [value]="option.id"
      [disabled]="option.disabled"
      [matTooltip]="option.tooltip"
    >
      <div [innerHtml]="option.label"></div>
      <button
        *ngIf="!option.cannotBeDeleted"
        (click)="deleteOption(option.id)"
        class="delete-action-button"
        mat-icon-button
      >
        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

And when i select an element i get this:

[image]

It adds "delete", that says to the MatIcon what icon i want, to the Option value. Have 0 ideas how to fix this.

Here is my select option and i need it that way by design:

[image]

**How to reproduce:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vz66pt?file=src/index.html

Open the dropdown and select any item

**Problem:**

"delete" has been added to the Dropdown value that you selected

Comment: Why would you want to show the delete icon inside the `mat-option`? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu I'd assume it is to remove the currently selected value. I've seen this kind of behavior in a lot of apps already.

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Did you expect an Icon to show up innstead of the `delete` text? Can you provide a reproducer to have a look at?

Comment: @MikeS. Not uncommon, but I saw many more of those next to the select control. This is the first time in a lot of years when I see one inside the option itself. That's why I asked, maybe he wants it to be displayed next to the control instead. As for the text instead of the icon, he's probably missing the icon font CSS file inside index.html

Comment: Add this in your index.html and see how that goes: `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu no, it appears exactly where i want it. Inside the option. Some options are not provided by the app, but user can create them themselves and must have an option to be deleted. I have added a image

Comment: @MikeS. Remove not the currently selected option, but a option from select dropdown. Added a screenshot

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu My icon appears as it should, the problem is not in lack of stylesheets. The problem is that select interpretates "delete" as a part of a Option value

Comment: It looks like an icon for me when I try on stackblitz. Can you try to reproduce on stackblitz as well?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Sorry for the delay. Added link to stackblitz in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source code for mat-select and [it looks like it grabs the `textContent`](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e383efd90425fd01ed9e19a7f956cfdaf2787668/src/material/core/option/option.ts#L113) of the `mat-option` whenever you select one, and just displays that thing.

One of the solutions that I found [in the examples section](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-custom-trigger) is to use the `mat-select-trigger` directive to control how the selected value is going to be displayed:

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <div [innerHtml]="selectedOption?.label"></div>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option
    *ngFor="let option of options"
    [value]="option"
    [disabled]="option.disabled"
    [matTooltip]="option.tooltip"
  >
    <div [innerHtml]="option.label"></div>
    <button
      *ngIf="!option.cannotBeDeleted"
      (click)="deleteOption(option.id)"
      class="delete-action-button"
      mat-icon-button
    >
      <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

You can also add the button back if that's what you want, by including it in the `mat-select-trigger`

```html
<mat-select-trigger>
  <div [innerHtml]="selectedOption?.label"></div>
  <button
    *ngIf="selectedOption && !selectedOption.cannotBeDeleted"
    (click)="deleteOption(selectedOption?.id)"
    class="delete-action-button"
    mat-icon-button
  >
    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-select-trigger>
```

In the `ts` file you only need to add the property that I bound to using the `ngModel` directive:

```
selectedOption: any | null = null;
```

Comment: You are the hero that saved my last hair pieces :)